# How to limit the text of RadGrid column with option to view more content

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Radgrid with a column Product Description. The product description is very long and it obscures the view for the user.

Please see attached picture

Radgrid Product Description View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvi2X.jpg

How can I hide portion of the text where a see more content extends the hidden text.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as the follows:

- Instead of using 'GridBoundColumn' use 'GridTemplateColumn' see code below:

**Designer View:**

```html
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Product_Description" HeaderText="Product Description" UniqueName="Product_Description">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Product_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# TrimDescription(Eval("Product_Description") as string) %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**Code View:**

```html
protected string TrimDescription(string description) { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) && description.Length > 200) { return string.Concat(description.Substring(0, 200), "..."); } return description; }
```

The page is only used to view a summary of the requested tables.

See screenshot: [image: Product Description]

Comment: This only partially solves the issue by just maximising the length of the column content which is trivial.

The OP asked "How can I hide portion of the text where a see more content extends the hidden text."

I have the same issue but like the OP I want to be able to click on the "see more" or "..." and see the entire text